# call different javascript functions based on html select values

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a html page with select combo box.

```
<select id="mySelect" name="Geometrical Figures">
  <option>Circle</option>
  <option>Triangle</option>
  <option>Square</option>
  <option>Rectangle</option>
  <option>Polygon</option>
</select>
<button  id="imagedraw" onclick="draw()">Draw Image</button>
```

I have different functions to draw canvas images based on user selection

```
function drawcircle()
function drawrectangle()
function drawtriangle()
```

My query is how can I set which function to call dynamically based on user input when `onclick` event is executed.
Ex: When user selects circle and clicks on Draw Image, `drawCircle()` function would be called, similarly for other values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can know the selected item by saving the `Select` element.

```
var mySelect = document.getElementById('MySelect');
var selected = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].text;
```

Then in the draw function you can add that and then decide what to do:

```
function draw(){
     var mySelect = document.getElementById('MySelect');
     var selected = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].text;
     if(selected === 'Circle'){
          drawCircle();
      }
 .........
}
```

There may be more viable solutions.

Comment: Thanks...all the above suggestions were mostly accurate!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe assign a `value` to each `option` and use a `switch` to decide which function to call?

You could also use the function name as `value` of the `option` and call the function by string:

```
<option value="drawCircle">Circle</option>

function draw() {
    window[document.getElementById("mySelect").value]();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create array of functions and call the function according to the selected option index.

```
var funcArray = [drawcircleFN,drawrectangleFN,drawtriangleFN];
var draw = function(){
    var yourSelect = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    var funcIndex = yourSelect.options[ yourSelect.selectedIndex ].value;
    funcArray[funcIndex]();
}
```