# create a canvas polygon in html5 with dynamic user input

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, polygon

Hi I want to create a polygon using html canvas based on dynamic user input i.e. the starting coordinates and angle. Here is the sample code.

```
     <canvas width="500" height="400" id="myCanvas"></canvas><br /><br />
     <script>
     var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
     var context = canvas.getContext('2d'); 

      function polygon(ctx, x, y, radius, sides, startAngle, anticlockwise)     {
       if (sides < 3) return;
       var a = (Math.PI * 2)/sides;
       a = anticlockwise?-a:a;
       ctx.save();
       ctx.translate(x,y);
       ctx.rotate(startAngle);
       ctx.moveTo(radius,0);
       for (var i = 1; i < sides; i++) {
       ctx.lineTo(radius*Math.cos(a*i),radius*Math.sin(a*i));
       }
       ctx.closePath();
       ctx.restore();

       }
      var centerX = document.getElementById("cood1").value; //Starting Coordinate 1
      var centerY = document.getElementById("cood2").value; //Starting Coordinate 2
      var centerZ = document.getElementById("cood3").value; //Circle Radius
      context.beginPath();
      polygon(context,centerX,centerY,centerZ,45,-Math.PI/2);
      context.fillStyle="rgba(227,11,93,0.75)";
      context.fill();
      context.stroke();
      </script>
```

The issue is the code is not working when I am making the starting coordinates and the radius(in case of polygon circle) dynamic.If I hard code the same its working...

polygon(context,50,50,50,45,-Math.PI/2);

Experts kindly share where I am going wrong!!

Comment: @John R....any inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your polygon function works as long as you are feeding it valid values.

Your problem is likely in fetching & validating your inputs. You must test if the inputs are numbers in valid ranges. Here's an example that tests if the `radius` input is valid.

```
// fetch the value in the #radius input element
var radius=parseInt(document.getElementById('radius').value);

// Reject any non-numbers
if(isNaN(radius)){alert('Radius must be a number');return;}

// Reject any numbers outside the valid range
if(radius<1){alert('Radius must be 1+');return;}
```

**Here's example code and a Demo:**

*This example code just validates "radius" but you must validate every input.*

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var x=150;
var y=150;
var sides=6;
var startAngle=0;
var anticlockwise=false;

document.getElementById('go').onclick=function(){
    var radius=parseInt(document.getElementById('radius').value);
    if(isNaN(radius)){alert('Radius must be a number');return;}
    if(radius<1){alert('Radius must be 1+');return;}
    polygon(ctx,x,y,radius,sides,startAngle,anticlockwise);
    ctx.stroke();
};

function polygon(ctx, x, y, radius, sides, startAngle, anticlockwise)     {
     if (sides < 3) return;
     var a = (Math.PI * 2)/sides;
     a = anticlockwise?-a:a;
     ctx.save();
     ctx.translate(x,y);
     ctx.rotate(startAngle);
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.moveTo(radius,0);
     for (var i = 1; i < sides; i++) {
        ctx.lineTo(radius*Math.cos(a*i),radius*Math.sin(a*i));
     }
     ctx.closePath();
     ctx.restore();
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
Radius:&nbsp <input type=text id='radius'>
<button id=go>Draw</button>
<br>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

BTW, You should always begin a new path with `.beginPath`. Otherwise all previous paths since the last .beginPath will be redrawn along with the new path.

Comment: Thanks @markE...I get your point!!

However there is one more confusion...I want to draw multiple geometrical figures.(polygon,hexagon etc)..hence I want to control the two parameters
var sides=5(in case of polygon)/6(in case of hexagon);
and harcode the same...
I am novice in js...is there I way I can specify the same in the same script?For Ex:

if(selected == 'Polygon'){
          var sides=5;

Kindly confirm.

Comment: Sure. You could add a select element with *Triangle, Rectangle, Pentagon, etc* options. Then fetch the select's `.value` and set the appropriate number of sides from the .value. See this mostly on-topic [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36816587/call-different-javascript-funtions-based-on-html-select-values/36819326#36819326) to get you started. Cheers!